# Sending request payload to rest api java modify the code without stream reader and writer in java

Tags: java

I am trying to modify my code without using buffered reader writer and stream method. can anyone suggest me how to simplify my code.

I am running this code in cucumber and it is running fine.

```
public String creatProduct() throws Throwable {
    String payload = "{"
            + "\"productName\":\"Macroon\","
            + "\"productCode\":\"\","
            + "\"externalRoomId\":\"\","
            + "\"description\":\"\""
            + "}";

    String requestUrl = "www.example.com";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        writer.write(payload);
        writer.close();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        connection.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Response==>" + jsonString.toString());
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("Input payload:" + payload);
        map = mapper.readValue(jsonString.toString(), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        });
        System.out.println("Output Map: " + map);
        map.get("productName");
        assertEquals("Macroon", map.get("productName"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return jsonString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code and it is working!

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
   PostMethod post = new PostMethod("www.example.com");
   post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(payload, "application/json", null));    
   httpclient.executeMethod(post);
   String jsonResponse = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
   System.out.println("Response==>"+jsonResponse);
   Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
   ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();  
   System.out.println("Input payload:"+ payload);
   map1 = mapper.readValue(jsonResponse, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>(){});
   System.out.println("Output Map: "+map1);
   map1.get("message");
   assertEquals("Success",map1.get("message"));
```